# geoexplorer add north panel

Tags: html, geoexplorer, ext-js-4

I need to add a header to my GeoExplorer application in the same way they do here http://demo.geonode.org/maps/new. Where should I modify the code to achieve this?

I try adding Ext.Panel within composer.js, but not the solution I think:

```
var northPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        region: "north",
        id: "north",
        height: 100,
        border: false,
        split: true,
        collapsible: false,
        collapseMode: "mini",
        collapsed: false,
        hideCollapseTool: true,
        header: true,
        layout: "border",
    renderto: function (){console.log("em composer ");console.log(document.body)},
        items: [{
            region: "center",
            id: "header",
            title: "header",
            layout: "fit"
        }]
    });
```

Also detected in the GeoExplorer/app/viewer.html there html code file, the one shown at the top of this link http://demo.geonode.org/maps/new, but I can not make this code display my GeoExplorer application.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a northpanel by extening GeoExplorer.Composer like is done here: https://github.com/Norwegian-marine-datacentre/arctic-roos/blob/master/src/main/webapp/javascript/norArgoComposer.js

Comment: But one thing important to emphasize: I intend to display a header (in a north panel), but still do not achieve as does the "GeoNode" software on your GeoExplorer application.